# Can't seem to get this function to work in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme

Here is what I have done so far:

```
(define sumOdd
    (lambda(n)
        (cond((> n 0)1)
             ((odd? n) (* (sumOdd n (-(* 2 n) 1)
```

output would look something like this:

```
 (sumOdd 1)  ==> 1
 (sumOdd 4)  ==> 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 ==> 16
 (sumOdd 5)  ==> 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 ==> 25
```

This is what I am trying to get it to do: find the sum of the first N odd positive integers

I can not think of a way to only add the odd numbers.

Comment: Your parentheses are unbalanced.

Answer (score 1):

Let's think about a couple of cases:

1) What should (sumOdd 5) return? Well, it should return 5 + 3 + 1 = 9.
2) What should (sumOdd 6) return? Well, that also returns 5 + 3 + 1 = 9.

Now, we can write this algorithm a lot of ways, but here's one way I've decided to think about it:

We're going to write a recursive function, starting at n, and counting down. If n is odd, we want to add n to our running total, and then count down by **2**. Why am I counting down by 2? Because if n is odd, n - 2 is also odd. Otherwise, if n is even, I do not want to add anything. I want to make sure that I **keep recursing**, however, so that I get to an odd number. How do I get to the next odd number, counting down from an even number? I subtract 1. And I do this, counting down until n is <= 0. I do **not** want to add anything to my running total then, so I return 0. Here is what that algorithm looks like:

```
(define sumOdd
  (lambda (n)
    (cond ((<= n 0) 0)
          ((odd? n) (+ n (sumOdd (- n 2))))
          (else (sumOdd (- n 1))))))
```

If it helps you, here is a more explicit example of a slightly different algorithm:

```
(define sumOdd
  (lambda (n)
    (cond ((<= n 0) 0)
          ((odd? n) (+ n (sumOdd (- n 1))))
          ((even? n) (+ 0 (sumOdd (- n 1))))))) ; note that (even? n) can be replaced by `else' (if its not odd, it is even), and that (+ 0 ..) can also be left out
```

EDIT:

I see that the problem has changed just a bit. To sum the first N positive odd integers, there are a couple of options.

First option: Math!

```
(define sumOdd (lambda (n) (* n n)))
```

Second option: Recursion. There are lots of ways to accomplish this. You could generate a list of 2*n and use the procedures above, for example.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate further on the `sum-odds` problem, you might solve it in terms of more abstract procedures that in combination accumulates the desired answer. This isn't necessarily the *easiest* solution, but it is *interesting* and captures some more general patterns that are common when processing list structures:

```
; the list of integers from n to m
(define (make-numbers n m)
  (if (= n m) (list n)                             ; the sequence m..m is (m)
      (cons n                                      ; accumulate n to 
            (make-numbers (+ n 1) m))))            ; the sequence n+1..m

; the list of items satisfying predicate
(define (filter pred lst)
  (if (null? lst) '()                              ; nothing filtered is nothing
      (if (pred (car lst))                         ; (car lst) is satisfactory
          (cons (car lst)                          ; accumulate item (car lst)
                (filter pred (cdr lst)))           ; to the filtering of rest
          (filter pred (cdr lst)))))               ; skip item (car lst)

; the result of combining list items with procedure
(define (build-value proc base lst)
  (if (null? lst) base                             ; building nothing is the base
      (proc (car lst)                              ; apply procedure to (car lst)
            (build-value proc base (cdr lst)))))   ; and to the building of rest

; the sum of n first odds
(define (sum-odds n)
  (if (negative? n) #f                             ; negatives aren't defined
      (build-value +                               ; build values with +
                   0                               ; build with 0 in base case
                   (filter odd?                    ; filter out even numbers
                           (make-numbers 1 n)))))  ; make numbers 1..n
```

Hope this answer was interesting and not too confusing.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer this actually helped me out width another problem i had

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 variables, one which keep counter of how many odd numbers are still to be added and another to hold the current odd number which gets increment by 2 after being used in addition:

```
(define (sum-odd n)
  (define (proc current start)
    (if (= current 0) 
        0
        (+ start (proc (- current 1) (+ start 2)) )))
    (proc n 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice tail recursive implementation:

```
 (define (sumOdd n)
  (let summing ((total 0) (count 0) (next 1))
    (cond ((= count n) total)
          ((odd? next) (summing (+ total next)
                                (+ count 1)
                                (+ next  1)))
          (else (summing total count (+ next 1))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter tail-recursive version:

```
(define (sumOdd n)
  (let loop ((sum 0) (n n) (val 1))
    (if (= n 0)
        sum
        (loop (+ sum val) (- n 1) (+ val 2)))))
```